# Is there a way to paste automatically a column name in an object?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, replace, paste

I have 2 `data.frame` with many columns.

I would like to obtain some information per column (I do permutation tests between these 2 `data.frame` like [this](http://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/permutation_tests.html) for each column), so I must use the name or the number of the column in an object (e.g. `object <-data_frame_n$colomn_name_n`) in my script.

Is there my script:

```
   quizz <- data_frame_1$colomn_name_1
   control <- data_frame_2$colomn_name_1
   obsdiff <- mean(quizz)-mean(control)

   N <- 12
   avgdiff <- replicate(1000, {
     all <- sample(c(control,quizz))
     newcontrols <- all[1:N]
     newquizz <- all[(N+1):(2*N)]
     return(mean(newquizz) - mean(newcontrols))
   })
   hist(avgdiff)
   abline(v=obsdiff, col="red", lwd=2)

   # the proportion of permutations with larger difference
   (sum(abs(avgdiff) > abs(obsdiff)) + 1) / (length(avgdiff) + 1)
```

Well, to obtain all my values, I lunch my script for every column by changing manually the name or the number of the column (e.g. for first value :

```
 quizz <- data_frame_1$colomn_name_1
 control <- data_frame_2$colomn_name_1
 ...
```

I lunch the script, I wrote the obtained value ;

for second value I change:

```
  quizz <- data_frame_1$colomn_name_2
  control <- data_frame_2$colomn_name_2
  ...
```

I lunch the script, I wrote the obtained value... etc).

So, is there a way to replace/paste automatically a column name from `data.frame` in an object ?
And better, is there a way to replace this and obtain a vector with all results ?

Thanks for enlightening my mind !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
colnames(df)
```

to get all the column names and

```
df[, "column1"] # equivalent to df$column1
```

to get a column. So you can have something like

```
columns <- colnames(df)
for (col in columns) {
    # do something with df[, col]
}
```

and I guess the rest of it depends on what you want to do.